# Ansible regex to parse multi-line .env file

Tags: regex, ansible

> Please note: there are always alternatives to this, but this is more of an interest / challenge - please focus on the question itself, specifically how to parse a .env file with a valid regex in Ansible. I'm very close.

I have a `.env` file that I'd like to parse into ansible variables within an ansible playbook. I currently have this working with simple `key=value` pairs, and also ignoring comments and new lines.

This is the regex replace that works:

`map('regex_replace', '([^=]*)=(.*)', '\\1: \\2')`

And the `.env` file it parses.

```
KEY2=SOME_TEXT
KEY3="SOME_MORE_TEXT"
KEY4='EVEN_MORE_TEXT'
```

### Problem

However, when I have a multi-line variable in this file, such as:

```
KEY1='{
    "string" = {
        "key" = "value",
        "key" = "value"
    }
}'
```

... then the regex still parses it, but it also changes all of the `=` into `:` within that string. I want to **ignore** anything within those single quotes, and I don't know how to do that.

Here is the necessary part of the playbook with the regex I have so far:

```
      set_fact:
        env_vars: "{{ (env_file_content.content | b64decode).split('\n') | map('regex_replace', '^#.*', '') | select | map('regex_replace', '([^=]*)=(.*)', '\\1: \\2') | join('\n') | from_yaml }}"
```

and the full `.env` file:

```
# IN TOTAL, THE REGEX SHOULD MATCH 4 KEY-VALUE PAIRS FROM THIS FILE.
KEY1='{
    "string" = {
        "key" = "value",
        "key" = "value"
    },
    "string" = {
        "key" = "value",
        "key" = "value"
    }
}'

# DO NOT MATCH ON COMMENTS, EVEN THOSE WITH X=Y in them.

# ALSO IGNORE THIS COMMENT, AND NEW LINES AROUND.

KEY2=SOME_TEXT
KEY3="SOME_MORE_TEXT"
KEY4='EVEN_MORE_TEXT'
```

### What I need

- The regex needs to yield four variables that can be accessed in Ansible such as `env_vars.KEY1`.
- The regex needs to *NOT* match anything *within* KEY1 - it needs to be left untouched.
- It also needs to prefix each key with `PREFIX_`, which can be done in the `regex_replace` with `'PREFIX_\\1: \\2'`, but you'll note that it prefixes everything within `KEY1` because it matches on the contents of that variable, when I want to ignore that.

How can I update what I have so far to parse a multi-line `.env` file with a Regex (and prefix each var with a string) in ansible so that I can access the four individual variables?

Comment: Perhaps like this `^([^"\s=]+)=('{[\s\S]*?\n}'|.*)` https://regex101.com/r/wFhI1e/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is exactly what I need, thanks so much! I was close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regex, you might use:

```
^([^"\s=]+)=('{[\s\S]*?\n}'|.*)
```

In the replacement you can use `PREFIX_\\1: \\2`

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^"\s=]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `"` and `=`
- `=` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `'{` Match `'{`
  - `[\s\S]*?` Match any character including newlines, as few as possible
  - `\n}'` Match a newline and then `}'`
  - `|` Or
  - `.*` Match the whole line without newlines
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFhI1e/1)

Comment: I'm trying to run this from terminal without sed, but I'm not quite sure how, so reading the `.env` file and exporting with this regex the newly prefixed values. The regex demo sed doesn't work (maybe because sed is different depending on O/S etc). `foo=$(cat .env); echo "${foo//^([^\"\s=]+)=('{[\s\S]*?\n}'|.*)/TEST_$1}"` doesn't add `TEST_` as I would've thought... And that's just to replace, never mind needing to use `xargs` or something to export these vars. Any chance you might know a quick and easy solution for that?

Comment: I've tried: `regex=s/^([^\"\s=]+)=('{[\s\S]*?\n}'|.*)/PREFIX_\1: \2/gm;t` then `sed -E '$regex' <<< $(cat .env)`. Nothing is prefixed.

Comment: @Jimbo I am not sure if you can use the pattern like that with sed, as sed replaces line by line. Using a non greedy quantifier also does not work in sed.